# Understanding ED impose PID

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Theorem:** Every Euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain.

**Proof:** For any ideal $I$, take a nonzero element of minimal norm $b$. Then $I$ must be generated by $b$, because for any $a \in I$ we have $a=bq+r$ for some $q.r$, with $N(r) < N(m$, and we must have $r=0$ otherwise would be a nonzero element of smaller norm than $b$, which is a contradiction.

The only part bothering me about is the proof is the first line. Why can we take a nonzero element of minimal norm in $I$?

Answer (score 1):

Because the set of the norms (of the elements of $I$) is a nonempty set of positive integers and so it has a minimum element (from the  well-ordering principle )

Comment: I think norm here need not be an integer.

Comment: @user330477 Isn't the norm $N:R-\{0\} \to\mathbb{N}$ ??

Answer (score 0):

Well, minimality is required a priori. Suppose $R$ is a Euclidean domain and $I \triangleleft R$. Then EITHER $I = {0} = (0)$ OR we can take $a  \neq  0$ in $I$ with $d(a)$ least; then for any $b \in I$, we can write $b = qa + r$ with $r = 0$ or $d(r) < d(a)$; but $r = q − ba \in I$ and so by minimality of $d(a)$, $r = 0$; thus $a|b$ and $I = (a)$.

Comment: I understand the proof, but can you explain the first line in a bit more detail.